# Analyzing motion of oscillating masses for angular frequency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency

[image]

If we replace the mass by a point mass, equate the forces in the diagram and do small angle approximation, we would reach at regular pendulum angular frequency formula
i.e:

$F=ma$

$-mg\sin \theta= ma$

$ -mg \frac{x}{L} = ma$

comparing with harmonic oscillator, we get

$ \omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$

But the correct answer is, $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{mgL}{I}}$

Where is the mistake??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular SHM and center of mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434232/angular-shm-and-center-of-mass)

Comment: you used torque balance , I used force balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace a physical pendulum with a point mass at the center of mass and get the same results. The systems are not analogous. The behavior of the pendulum depends on how the mass of the pendulum is distributed, not just on how much mass there is and where the center of mass is.

The reason this doesn't work is because we are looking at the differential equation $$\frac{\text d^2\theta}{\text dt^2}=\frac{\tau}{I}$$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia. This value depends on the *squared* distance the mass is from the pivot point of the pendulum, and thus we cannot just move all mass to the center of the mass.

However, you can go the other way: For a simple pendulum with a length of $l$, the moment of inertia of the point mass is $I=ml^2$ so then $mgl/I=mgl/ml^2=g/l$

Comment: Why not? What exactly is going wrong when I do that? like which step reflects the distribution of mass thing

Comment: @DDD4C4U See my edit

Comment: @DDD4C4U because there’s torque acting on the system as well.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish I don't think torque is sufficient to explain it all. The same torque is present in either case actually, since you are allowed to pretend like gravity is just acting at the center of mass. However, the moment of inertia doesn't allow you to do this

Comment: Yes, the system’s response to torque is dependent on the moment of inertia. That is what I meant to say.

Comment: @BioPhysicist considering the torque is not *necessary* to explain it. Just find the potential and kinetic energy of the system. The KE includes $I\omega^2$ as well as $mv^2$.

Comment: @alephzero Sure that's another way. I don't think I ever claimed my explanation is necessary, but it is sufficient.